# Which is grammatically correct: "if someone was starving" or "if someone were starving"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, subjunctive-mood, irrealis-were

Which sentence is more grammatically correct:

- If someone **was** starving on an island
- If someone **were** starving on an island

Comment: I didn't realize it was necessary to capitalize the beginning word of a sentence fragment. It's something I normally wouldn't choose to do. (Re: the most recent edit of the question).

Answer (score 2):

> "if someone was starving on an island"

This denotes the factual condition of whether someone was at an earlier time starving.

> "if someone were starving on an island"

This denotes a hypothetical, as opposed to a factual statement about something already happened. Using "were" in this case is known as the subjunctive mood. If it's this use you're using then "were" is the correct one. This is much like saying:

> "If someone happened to be starving on an island, would you help
>   him?"

Subjunctive mood

> Subjunctive forms of verbs are typically used to express various
>   states of unreality such as wish, emotion, possibility, judgment,
>   opinion, obligation, or action that have not yet occurred
>   [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood)
>
> Examples:
>  The past subjunctive
>  "If I were rich I would buy a
>   Ferrari."
>  "I wish I were taller."
>  "If only he were here
>   now!"
>  [Collins Dictionary](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/the-subjunctive)

Use of the past subjunctive:

> "If I were your wife, I would put poison in your coffee."
>  [Wikipedia article on English subjunctive](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive)

The subjunctive mood in other languages is more obligatory and its misuse is less acceptable. However in English using the simple past in place of where the subjunctive mood should be used is quite commonplace, especially informally. It's more strongly delineated in other languages using completely different inflections/conjugations, and in English I think it's harder to detect.

> In Modern English, the subjunctive form of a verb often looks
>   identical to the indicative form, and thus subjunctives are not a very
>   visible grammatical feature of English.
>
> [English subjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive)

Comment: This was a one + answer, but would you explain why the OP used the question mark for the second example, and vice versa. (was it a typo, maybe?)

Comment: @haha As to why the OP used a question mark in the second sentence, I assume they marked it such because they were unsure if it was valid. About why I used a question mark in one of my examples that ended "would you help him?", that was just my addition to complete the sentence. Maybe I should remove it.

Comment: @haha Thank you (I forgot to remove the question mark when I edited it).

Comment: You are welcom.